# How do you cover a MapBox map with a semi-transparent overlay?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I would like to put an `opacity: 0.7` [layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-property) over the whole map, but in between the geography tiles and some dots I'm going to draw at specific lat/lngs. How can I add a semi-transparent overlay to a MapBox map in between my dots and the land/water?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code from the mapbox-gl lib
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/adjust-layer-opacity/

Its basically a part of the style specification, where you need to create a layer on map styles

Comment: That uses another raster map as a layer, not simply doing a fill. I saw that one, but it doesn't really help I don't think.

Comment: As far as i understand we need to create a layer on top of the map and then set the opacity to it.. are you saying that you wish to set the opacity on the map container.

Comment: I don't want to set it on the map container, on an overlay within the map. I need to see a full example.

Comment: In that case you will need to follow the above link, yes i understand its a raster tile but you can style it as per your choosing,Just take a look at the jsfiddle link provided down the link [https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/]

More specifically here is that part of the code that can be changed/styles as per your choosing 
        map.addSource('chicago', {
            'type': 'raster',
            'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.u8yyzaor'
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'chicago',
            'source': 'chicago',
            'type': 'raster'
        });

Comment: I don't have a `url: mapbox://`, I have a canvas which I need to be opaque. How do I do it like that?

Comment: Since i do not have your code I took the canvas example from Mapbox site [ https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/canvas-source/ ]  and added ` ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2; ` at the end of ` this.draw = function () {} ` that made those randomly moving circles opac.

For "How can I add a semi-transparent overlay to a MapBox map in between my dots and the land/water?" you probably need to create a new layer on your canvas and then set the opacity